# from microscopic to kinetic transport theory

Tags: statistical-mechanics, hamiltonian-formalism

One way to model the dynamics of particles is to find the differential equation of motion of a particle. Of course, this will be nice and easy to do if we have only a few particles (like one-ish, without any constraints). It would be hysterically impossible to attempt doing this for the other of $10^{23}$ particles.

So I am reading some lectures and it says: one approach is to focus on the one-particle distribution function.

My question is: I do not understand why we deal with only one particle? Do we deal with one particle first and then go on to $N$? Please also given an intuitive explanation on this formulation. I am familiar with Liouville's and Hamiltonians to get to this point.

Thanks

Comment: You are correct, one particle distributions are not sufficient. The general (and generally pretty limited, if I am not mistake) theoretical approach is this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BBGKY_hierarchy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In principle one can always write down the differential equations for a system of $N$ particles and attempt to solve them: as you pointed out, there is no general solution if usually $N>2$. As such, nevertheless the need to describe features of general systems remains. The key point here is understanding that, as a matter of fact, whenever dealing with system formed by a very large amount of particles, as for example $N\sim 10^{23}$, one is no more interested in the singular dynamics, rather in general macroscopic quantities that result as averages and expectation values of the underlying kinetic quantities with respect to the particle distribution in the system. Examples of such macroscopic values are the average temperature, the average number of particles, the volume, the pressure, the free energy and so on and so forth.

In order to calculate all the above we introduce the *assumption* that a system possesses density distribution functions $\rho$ (also known as [statistical ensambles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_ensemble_%28mathematical_physics%29)) such that, by **definition**, the average quantities we are looking at can be calculated as expectation values
$$
E(X)=\int dX\,\rho(X)\,X
$$
where $X$ refers to the value for the single particle. Notice that the above does not have to hold true in general and is just a characterisation of some simple systems (ideal gas, for example, or particles in a box with well-behaving potential). The interpretation of the above equation is, as stated, that the macroscopic quantities emerge as expectation values, weighted with any some distribution, of the single quantities each particle has. The next step is then how to give explicit mathematical form to $\rho(X)$: in general each system has its own distribution function, whose features characterise the model at hand and have to be specified on a case by case basis. This said, there are some common derivation methods that you can find in the literature based on consistency criteria (any textbook in statistical mechanics).

Last but not the least, note that the above description only works for *very* large numbers of particles in *some* conditions: other than that, different methods have to be used (and there are diverse areas of statistical mechanics trying to address the problem).